# PCManFM custom directory icons

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, pcmanfm

I'd like PCManFM to show custom icons for my work folders;

for example to show the *AndroidDev* folder in this picture (italian locale here):

[image]

like this (Gimp used):

[image]

I saw the other folder icons are located in the /usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/ directory; for example the Image folder icon is folder_images.svg (or folder-images.svg).

- How do PCManFM knows that for "*Immagini*" folder he has to use the folder-images.svg icon?
- How can I instruct PCManFM to use for "*AndroidDev*" folder the folder-myicon.svg?

Answer (score -1):

Install the package xdg-user-dirs and then run xdg-user-dirs-update. This will create the configuration files that will allow your icon theme to use the special folder icons.

See the Arch Wiki for more info https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories